# Spherical rain drop gaining mass

Tags: classical-mechanics

> A spherical rain drop, falling in a constant gravitational field, grows by the absorption of moisture from the surrounding at a rate proportional to its surface area. If it starts with zero radius, find its acceleration.

**My attempt**
My assumptions are $m$ is mass of the rain drop, $r$ is the radius of the rain drop, $\rho_w$ is density of the rain drop, $\vec{g}$ is gravity, $\vec{F}$ is the downward force, $t$ is time and $v$ is the instantaneous speed.

$\frac{dm}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \cdot K = \frac{d}{dt} m = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho_w) = \frac{4}{3}\pi \rho_w \frac{dr^3}{dt}  = 4\pi \rho_w r^2  \frac{dr}{dt}.$\
This  implies $dt = dr \rho_w/K $.

Now, $\vec{F} = \frac{d}{dt}(mv)  =  \frac{4}3 \pi \rho_w\frac{d}{dt}(r^3v )$.  By substituting $dt$ by $dr \rho_w/K $ on this equation, one can see that  $\vec{F} = \frac{4}3 \pi K\frac{d}{dt}(r^3v) $.
Here comes the confusing bit. I don't  know what to do with $\vec{F}$. First I thought taking $\vec{F} = m\vec{g} = \frac{4}3 \pi \rho_w r^3 \cdot \vec{g} $. When I do that I end up with $\dfrac{d}{dt}r^3 v = \frac{\rho_w r^3 v }{K} \implies v = \frac{\rho_w \vec{g} r }{K}. $ and ultimately $dv/dt = \vec{g}/4$. But then I realized, if there is something that can reduce the acceleration (from gravitational acceleration), then the magnitude  of $ \vec{F}$ should be less than the magnitude  of $ m\vec{g} = \frac{4}3 \pi \rho_w r^3 \cdot \vec{g}$ because of the drag force reducing the magnitude of $\vec{g}$. Can anyone say anything about this or even propose another solution? I apologize for the errors or informalities in the question in advance.

Comment: Well, the drag coefficient wasn't listed as a given quantity. It would be strange to introduce such a quantity in a problem when they made it a point to define every apparently relevant quantity. I'd say if they wanted you to include the drag force, they ought to have mentioned the drag coefficient.

Comment: The question is a bit strange, IMHO. At first, I thought it was asking for the acceleration in the *size* of the raindrop, rather than it's vertical position. Raindrops quickly reach their terminal velocity (although that velocity changes as the drop's size changes), so it's a bit weird to neglect air resistance if you want to model the drop's fall realistically. My *guess* is that they're testing to see if you answer the question using *only* the given information, and if you use other information you will lose marks.

Comment: @electronpusher Honestly, the question didn't give the 'givens'. I just added them to avoid confusions on my attempt. This means you can add any quantity if you think it is important. I will go edit the question to avoid such misunderstanding.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry, I think I gave the wrong impression when I quoted the 'givens' together. I have edited the question. You can add any quantity to the "given" if you think it is important.

Comment: @user669545 In that case I'd recommend including drag. As you may know, the Drag Equation gives an expression for the drag force (which is quadratic in velocity). I also think this question is a bit strange (all the more interesting), where did it come from?

Comment: @electronpusher A friend sent it to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you got the right answer but were missing the physical intuition and mathematical confidence necessary to believe your answer:

Let’s assume that the problem meant us to start with an infinitesimal speck of a raindrop, rather than truly zero radius (which could never grow and would make for a pretty boring situation!)

Let us also observe that the radius of the raindrop must increase at a constant rate.    How will the raindrop move?   The answer might not be immediately obvious.

There is a clear reason for the acceleration to be less than *g*.  All of the absorbed water which is hitching onto the raindrop as the raindrop falls is doing so **with zero initial momentum**!  When the raindrop is small, it is also falling slowly.  So while the presently absorbed water is massive relative to the drop, it does not need to be accelerated much.  When the raindrop is large, it is also falling quickly.  So while the presently absorbed water is less massive relative to the drop, it must be accelerated significantly.

It turns out that when you do the math, as you already did, these effects balance each other perfectly and the result is constant acceleration at one quarter *g*!!   So your answer was correct, although I think I see a couple typos in the intermediate steps.  What a beautifully unexpected result!

I will be adding this to my “very cool AP physics problems” file.

P.S. Another potential surprise here is the fact that the movement of the drop is independent of *K*!      This is caused by another case of perfectly balanced opposing effects.  At the same drop size, the drop will be moving faster (at a later time) for smaller *K*, which balances the reduced rate of absorbtion perfectly.

Comment: Why must the radius increase at a constant rate? There are multiple effects at play - at larger radius there is more surface area so faster volumetric growth, so faster radial growth, but that growth is more spread out so it may provide lower radial growth than expected. How can we be sure constant radial growth is a reasonable assumption?

Comment: @electronpusher The argument is purely mathematical.  If the absorption is proportional to surface area, then in each dt, a shell of the same thickness dr is added to the surface, so dr/dt is a constant, as already appears in the question statement.  This was something the questioner already knew.

Comment: I see, I glanced over the math too fast. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You mention you were not sure to do with $\vec{F}$. The guiding equation in this problem is Newton's second law of motion, $\sum \vec{F} =m\vec{a}$. If you want to included drag, then you have two forces on the object, giving $\sum \vec{F} = \vec{F_g}+\vec{F_d}$. This may then be equated to $m\vec{a}$. The drag equation gives $\vec{F_d}=-\frac{1}{2}C_d \rho A v^2 \hat{v}$. The factor $-\hat{v}$ means that this force is directed opposite the motion of the object. $A$ is the maximum cross sectional area of the object (in this case $\pi r^2$, which grows with time). $C_d$ is the drag coefficient which is a dimensionless parameter determined empirically, but you might be able to use 0.47 if you desire a numeral result (valid for a sphere in a fluid at Reynold's Numbers around $10^4$). $\rho$ is the density of the fluid medium (not the object). You should now be equipped to carry out your calculation.

Comment: There is no fluid mechanics or drag in this problem…

Comment: @DuncanHarris Perhaps it miraculously cancels out as you said, but a priori I think fluid mechanics should be considered, as we have a fluid moving through a fluid.

Comment: it doesn’t cancel out, it just isn’t part of the scope of the problem!  This problem is about the surprising fact that you can make a reasonable approximation and get a meaningful answer even without much of any information about density, size, rate of accumulation, etc.  Note the the problem spells out a uniform g, but doesn’t mention air density or even the presence of air.

Comment: How do we know it's a reasonable approximation?

Comment: We don’t.  If the problem were about realistic behavior of real raindrops on earth, it could simply read “construct a detailed model of the behavior of a raindrop falling inside a cloud”.  As in many physics exercises, the author has their own particular model in mind, and hints at it with their problem statement.  For what it is worth, the problem also works out fairly neatly with a linear drag force, but I do not think that is what the author intended.

Comment: Personally I don't think there's enough context or detail in the problem statement to assume that air resistance isn't within the scope of the problem. Assumptions are of course a routine part of science and engineering, but I find it unreasonable to claim it is clear here exactly what assumptions the author did and did not intend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140226/discussion-between-duncan-harris-and-electronpusher).